# Symfony & Doctrine Pulling ID from DB

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to write a function that when called will return the ID of the latest entry into my DB. I'm fairly new to PHP so please forgive me for my poor code.

```
public function devicesFunctionAction()
{   
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery(
      'SELECT id 
      FROM AppBundle:ZeusUsers
      ORDER BY id DESC');
    $id = $query->getResult();
    $query->setMaxResults(1);

    return new Response(json_encode(array('key' => $id)));
}
```

The above code produces a 500 error however it seems to be the 'BY' causing this:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 48: Error: Expected end of string, got
>   'BY' (500 Internal Server Error)

After reading the Doctrine documentation they use 'ORDER BY' in their example so I can't understand why it is causing such a issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, can easily provide more info if this is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not pure SQL you cannot do it like this with doctrine unless you use $connection->prepare() and execute() but to answer your question use it like this :

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery(
      'SELECT z.id
      FROM AppBundle:ZeusUsers z
      ORDER BY z.id DESC');
    $query->setMaxResults(1); // and setMaxResults(1) before getResult() obvisouly :p
    $id = $query->getSingleScalarResult();
```

## EDITED.

Comment: That works now however it outputs this: {"key":[{}]} - Any idea why it hasn't got an ID in it?

Comment: the result should be an object of type ZeusUsers if an id is what you want you should use a different query, well change it a bit :)